# Is it possible to prevent modifications to the title of a Google Doc yet allow the contents of the Google Doc to be edited

Tags: google-docs

### My Problem

I want to be able to migrate my Google Docs to a **regular website** while maintaining the links I had created between my Google Docs. Frequently I link one Google Doc to another Google Doc. As a result, I have created something that is similar to a wiki. For example let’s suppose I had created two Google Docs: Google Doc #1 and Google Doc #2.

Subsequently let’s suppose I had created a link (a hyperlink) in Google Doc #1 to Google Doc #2. Of course that's an extremely simple example. Let’s make it more complex. Imagine I had created a couple of thousand Google Docs with many links (hyperlinks) between them.

Of course backing up those Google Docs would be trivial either by using Google Takeout or rsync. However, what would happen if I wanted to move those Google Docs to a **regular website**? Then the myriad hyperlinks I had created would fail to point to the documents on my regular website.

That is, on my regular website, if I were to click on the link on the page which contained the contents which had been contained in Google Doc #1 (https://my_regular_website.com/google_doc_001) then instead of opening a link on my regular website to the page which contained the contents which had been contained in Google Doc #2 (https://my_regular_website.com/google_doc_002) , the link would point to the original Google Doc #2 (https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/google_doc_002)

### My Technical Question

I read that, “You can use the 'contentRestrictions.readOnly' field on a `file' resource to lock a file and prevent modifications to the title, uploading a new revision, and addition of comments.” Source: [Protect file content from modification](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/file-locking)

However, I would like to prevent modifications to the title file yet allow the contents of the file to be edited. For example,  I might name a file something like, “1cn2OX4U67mY925GzG80hRBYjpqq2conSi9xgYikgwIM” which is the unique portion of a Google Docs URL.

That way, on my regular website, by using a simple regex, I could “relink” documents that pointed to  https://docs.google.com/document/d/1cn2OX4U67mY925GzG80hRBYjpqq2conSi9xgYikgwIM

### Final Thoughts

I like using Google Docs as, dare I say it, a word processor. Sometimes I use Google Docs to write essays. Sometimes I use Google Docs to create documentation. Sometimes I use Google Docs to collaborate with others (instead of emailing). Furthermore, I often use Google Docs’ outline format, styles, and voice typing.

Sure, I suppose I could use an actual wiki. But although I’ve tried many different wikis over the years, I never enjoyed using them. I found them to be clunky and overly simplistic. Furthermore, I didn’t enjoy installing them and needing to back them up. At this point In time, I don't want to have to install and maintain any software on a VPS (virtual private server).

Answer (score 0):

I checked the documentation you are referring to and what you are trying to achieve is not possible, making a document read only will prevent a new revision of the file to be created.

For instance that won't allow you to change comments, content and title. At this time it is not possible to prevent some modifications, just all or none.

Regards.

Comment: Sadly, I guess you are probably correct. Thanks for taking the time to comment.